# Automatic row numbering in javafx table

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I have a sample code that we use to dynamic row numbers in `Java` `Swing` Table i.e `JTable`. I new to `JavaFX` and would like to the same in `JavaFX`. Is there is any way to set automatic row numbers in `JavaFX` Table

```
 class LineNumberTable extends JTable {

            private JTable mainTable;

            public LineNumberTable(JTable table) {
                super();
                mainTable = table;
                setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
                setModel(mainTable.getModel());
                setAutoscrolls(false);
                addColumn(new TableColumn());
                getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(mainTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());
                getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
                setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(getPreferredSize());

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                if (col == uneditableColumn) {
                    return false;
                }
                return bEdit;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                return Integer.valueOf(row + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowHeight(int row) {
                return mainTable.getRowHeight();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your Swing JTable to make it clear what you are after?

Comment: @UrsReupke Please refer this screen shot. http://zss.s3.amazonaws.com/Untitled.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1361989789&Signature=DF6NRn6l4HyYHiEV3o3MHM3XMao%3D. You can see the screen shot of swing table that having row numbers in his first column generated by above code and would like the same in javafx. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaFX, you use [`TableColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html)s with CellFactories and CellValueFactories to populate your `TableView`.

The JavaFX tutorials have an [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) that might get you started.

In one approach I have used I convert the business objects to display into presentation objects and add all necessary properties (like in your case, the number) to them.

EDIT: In a second, cleaner approach, you could set your CellFactory to create a `TableCell` that shows its own `index` property in `TableCell#updateItem(S, boolean)`:

```
public class NumberedCell extends TableCell{

  protected void updateItem(Object object, boolean selected){
    setText(String.valueOf(getIndex());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you.

Comment: I believe the boolean parameter to updateItem is "empty" instead of "selected". Not a big deal, but could be confusing to readers.

Comment: Also an @Override annotation would be reasonable – and, to be syntactically correct, a closing parenthesis at setText() ... ;)