# Why can you use the same generic type for both generic types in a TableColumn<T, S>?

Tags: java, generics, javafx

In the answers to this question: [Automatic row numbering in javafx table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449707/automatic-row-numbering-in-javafx-table)

I found the following solution to the original question:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class NumberedTableViewSample extends Application {

private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
private final ObservableList<Person> data =
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
    );

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(470);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn numberCol = new TableColumn("#");
    numberCol.setMinWidth(20);
    numberCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, Person>, ObservableValue<Person>>() {
        @Override public ObservableValue<Person> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, Person> p) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue());
        }
    });

    numberCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Person>, TableCell<Person, Person>>() {
        @Override public TableCell<Person, Person> call(TableColumn<Person, Person> param) {
            return new TableCell<Person, Person>() {
                @Override protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (this.getTableRow() != null && item != null) {
                        setText(this.getTableRow().getIndex()+"");
                    } else {
                        setText("");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
    numberCol.setSortable(false);

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(numberCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static class Person {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }
}
```

}

However, my question is:
Why can you use

`TableColumn<Person, Person> and TableCell<Person, Person>`

when the actual type of a cell is the type of TableColumn and not again a Person? JavaDoc says the second Type should be:

`S - The TableView type T - The TableColumn type`

The code somehow works, but can you please explain why both types are Person, although the numbered column only contains numbers? This might help to understand the code.

As far as I understand it the type of the TableView should be Person and the type of a TableColumn is something like String or int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is the type of the objects that are contained in the respective column.

As you already mentioned, the columns usually contain a single *property* that was obtained from a `Person`, like a `String` or an `Integer`.

However, in this case, the first column simply contains all the `Person` objects. They are not displayed. You could display them by changing the line

```
setText(this.getTableRow().getIndex()+"");
```

to

```
setText(this.getTableRow().getIndex()+": "+item);
```

But alternatively, you could also use `SomethingElse` as the second type:

```
class SomethingElse {}

TableColumn<Person, SomethingElse> numberCol = new TableColumn<Person, SomethingElse>("#");
numberCol.setMinWidth(20);
numberCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, SomethingElse>, ObservableValue<SomethingElse>>() {
    @Override public ObservableValue<SomethingElse> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, SomethingElse> p) {
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<SomethingElse>(new SomethingElse());
    }
});

numberCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, SomethingElse>, TableCell<Person, SomethingElse>>() {
    @Override public TableCell<Person, SomethingElse> call(TableColumn<Person, SomethingElse> param) {
        return new TableCell<Person, SomethingElse>() {
            @Override protected void updateItem(SomethingElse item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (this.getTableRow() != null && item != null) {
                    setText(this.getTableRow().getIndex()+"");
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

It's only used for enumerating the rows (and, by the way, a confusingly complicated way to do this)

Comment: Hm so the type written in the <> is not necessarily the one shown, but it's the one contained and it's contained in order to count the persons?
And that is why it could also be anything else?
I *think* I understand.

Comment: Do you know an even better way to do it, which is not as confusing? I wouldn't like adding an index to my Vocable type (in my own code it's about vocables)

Comment: @Zelphir Sorry, I'm not sooo familiar (yet) with the JavaFX tables, so I can't give a specific hint here (but I think that there *has* to be an easier way to achieve a simple line numbering - these nested inner classes and generic types look just scary...)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, every other column is of the type  or could be  or even  etc.

As it's defined by the beans with the PropertyValueFactory:

```
emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
```

However, the first column you don't just one pass an information of the person as the class Person doesn't have any index or other number. So when you create the number column as:

```
TableColumn<Person, Person> numberCol = new TableColumn<Person, Person>("#");
```

You are creating a "[meta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)" column and by that you are using persons to create the elements of such column (as you can see you get the index of the person to fill it). In fact the column have Persons, but its purpose is to have a column which will complete information that aren't exactly from the class Person but is relevant to be in the table.

Comment: So why take `Person` then? If I understand Marco13's answer correctly, you could use an arbitrary class in the brackets <> in this case. Maybe the author chose `Person` simply because they didn't want to use something completely unrelated?