# Update index of row in Tableview in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, count, tableview, row

I have this problem: in a tableview I have a column that count the number of file. In this moment I have 3 file...
but when I delete a row (i.e. the 2') the result is:
[tableview error count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQcDa.png)
then, when I add another file, you can see that it continue to count correctly:
[Tableview correctly count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KeLf.png)
How can I do to update the count of the 2' filename?
Thank you all

This is the code of the two function addFile and removeFile:

```
    public void addFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Seleziona il file da caricare");
        //imposta i filtri nel FileChooser
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());        
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
            //aggiunge nome del file e il conteggio nella tabella FX
            int count = Table.getItems().size()+1;
            Table.getItems().add(new PopulateTable(count, fileName, "DateToFind"));

        }
    }

    public void removeFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {
        Table.setEditable(true);
        int selectedIndex = Table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            Table.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);      
        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("No Selection");
            alert.setHeaderText("Nessun file audio selezionato!");
            alert.setContentText("Selezionare file audio in tabella");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
```

This is my code now in class Controller:

```
public void addFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Seleziona il file da caricare");
    //imposta i filtri nel FileChooser
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());        
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
        //aggiunge nome del file e il conteggio nella tabella FX

        Table.getItems().add(new PopulateTable( fileName, "DataDaTrovare"));

    }


count.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<PopulateTable, Void>() {
    @Override
    public void updateIndex(int index) {
        super.updateIndex(index);
        if (isEmpty() || index < 0) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(Integer.toString(index));
        }
    }
});

Table.getColumns().add(count);


}
private <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createColumn(String title,
        Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property, double width) {
    TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    col.setPrefWidth(width);
    return col;

    }
}
```

In console:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate TableColumns detected in TableView columns list with titles 'Index

Comment: It doesn't seem to me to make any sense to store the index (`count`) in the model object. The index is already determined by the index of the object in the table's list. You can simply create a column that displays that index, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353014/creating-a-row-index-column-in-javafx)

Comment: Thank you but I've already seen them, but I could not solve my problem...

Comment: What actually is the problem? What happens if you try it the way shown in Jose examples?

Comment: I edited my question for this my new problem.